# How to create a view or computed table using EF

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am using Entity Framework Code First in my ASP.NET MVC application. How to create a **View** in database to fetch the record from both the below tables using JOIN.

```
class Department
{
    [Key]
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Location { get; set; }
    public List<Employee> Employees { get; set; }
}

class Employee
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    [Column("First_Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    [Column("Last_Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
    public int DepartmentId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DepartmentId")]
    public Department Department { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Ok, what did you try so far?

Comment: I am new to EF Code First looking for the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using  Database.ExecuteSqlCommand() you can fire any kind of DDL Command.

```
using(var edb = new EmployeeDB()
{
edb.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("CREATE VIEW MyView AS SELECT TOP 3 
e.First_Name, e.Last_Name, e.Gender, e.Salary, d.Name as Deparment_Name, 
d.Location as Department_Location FROM tblEmployees e JOIN tblDepartments d on 
e.DepartmentId=d.DepartmentId");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create one model as required return type of your view, then create 
views inside a Migration using the Sql method:

```
public partial class Migration : DbMigration
{
  public override void Up()
  {
      this.Sql("CREATE VIEW dbo.MyView AS (etc)");
  }

  public override void Down()
  {
      this.Sql("DROP VIEW dbo.MyView");
  }
}
```

There's not any problem to map an entity to a view, in your dbContext:

```
public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
  public DbQuery<MyModelView> MyView
  {
     get
     {
        // Don't track changes to query results
        return Set<MyModelView>().AsNoTracking();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Saneesh, i am trying this code but this statement "Set<MyModelView>().AsNoTracking()" throw and error. **System.InvalidOperationException: 'The entity type MyModel is not part of the model for the current context.'**  But thanks..